# Vue Router how to load the second component load

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to load the second component inside my Vue but it will not load at all.
Think of home as my master page where other pages will load but I want it to load the front as soon as home is loaded because I have children routes as well.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <topbar></topbar>
    <div class="container mx-auto bg-gray-300">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Home' }">Home</router-link>
    </div>
    <div>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'About' }">About Page</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>

    <router-view name="frontPage"></router-view>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import topbar from "./../../components/TopbarComponent.vue";
import hooperCompo from "./../../components/HooperComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "This is the home component!",
    };
  },
  components: {
    topbar,
    hooperCompo,
  },
  computed: {},
  mounted: () => {},
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

here is my router links

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        components: {
            default: Home,
            frontPage: Front
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: "/about",
                name: "About",
                component: About
            }
        ]
    },
```

how do I make the front page component load as soon home is loaded ???

Comment: is `Front` a sub-component of  `Front`?, if yes then render it inside of `Home` template.

Comment: Home is a master page but i want when home is loaded load front in home

Comment: Them as I said render Front inside the template of Home

Comment: but if i do that , when i click on about i can see front as well

Comment: <router-view name="frontPage"></router-view> , i want this to render the front inside home so when i go to About page , i reneder About page inside home <router-view></router-view> and dont show front